# Is there a way to have changes to pkgs permeate throughout the nix configuration?

Tags: nix

I'm new to NixOs and trying to find my feet. I'd like to have a number of channels available in `pkgs` when importing it into various modules, so that I can pick and choose a bit. I'm using the approach described here:

https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Flakes#Importing_packages_from_multiple_channels, where a simple overlay is used to updated `pkgs`.

I've created this overlay in a `channels.nix`, which I'm then importing into my `configuration.nix`.

This works in that I can then use eg

```
 environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
   vim
   unstable.xterm
]
```

Where `unstable` is one of the channels I have defined in `channels.nix`, which is exactly as intended.

I then tried the same thing in my `home.nix`, eg

```
home.packages = with pkgs; [ 
  any-nix-shell
  unstable.alacritty
]
```

Which does not work - nix does not recognize unstable as being a valid attribute. So do I need to specifically pass the updated `pkgs` to the `imports = [ ./home.nix ]` statement? The syntax for doing so seems slightly convoluted so this seems non-idiomatic.

I would have thought that lazy evaluation would have some bearing here, but it's not entirely obvious to me how.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: `unstable` seems to just not defined in home.nix - either you need to define it (as you did for configuration.nix) or import a common module/file that defines it.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski - thanks - yes, this is what I ended up doing (defining my channels in a `channels.nix`, then importing that in both `configuration.nix` and `home.nix`. `configuration.nix` does itself import `home.nix`, so this feels at risk of circular imports, but it's working at the moment.

Comment: Alternatively you can also put the overlay in a file and add the location to the NIX_PATH, e.g. save the overlay as `/etc/nixos/overlays/unstable.nix` and then add `nix.nixPath = options.nix.nixPath.default ++ [ "nixpkgs-overlays=/etc/nixos/overlays" ]` to your `configuration.nix`.  See also https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Overlays